# MapInfo 12 Legend settings

Tags: legend, mapinfo

Does anyone know how (if) I can set the defaults within Legend Designer?  I want my rectangles for each layer to default to a 20x20 square, not a rectangle.  At the moment I have to change it manually for each layer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the edit to the question, defaults can be set here:

**Options > Preferences > Legend Window**

[image]